# Eclipse and subversion installation madness! Or is it just me?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am about to go crazy here!!! does anyone know how to install subversion for eclipse and how you set up your repositrory on a server - I take it you need Helios version??  It can't be done with Europa I believe.

The installation instructions are insane, go to different sites, update software from this link - hop on one leg, install when it's a full moon.  This is driving me crazy there is no clear instruction it's all over the place!!!

All I need is a list: a clear software stack and methodical instructions that make sense (and work).  Grrrrrr....

PS - I fully take on board I should re-read the installation instructions at least 39 times in order to get the software installed.

Comment: Which variant are you trying to install, and have you tried Subclipse?

Comment: I second subclipse too, it is very painless to use it with eclipse. Outside of eclipse I recommend Tortoise SVN for SVN usage.

Comment: I think, if I am not mistaken I was trying to follow the instructions and install for Subversive, not Subclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on Eclipse side it should be easy, just add the following link as an update site. Go to "Help" --> "install new software" --> "add" --> http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x

On the server side, creating an version control system isn't trivial. But I did that once and it's working quite good. A good howto you can find here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-subversion-with-web-access-on-ubuntu/

Unfortunately it's for ubuntu, but it was working for me and I think it can help you understanding the basic steps of installing subversion.

Comment: One thing I'd like to add is that you have to make sure that you're running Eclipse with enough permissions to modify the file system where eclipse is installed